# Recursively accumulate a path to an array from a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find all the child elements of a node in the following Javascript Object.

```
var graphObj = {

        a : {
            'true' : ['e', 'i'],
            'false' : ['u'],
            'blah' : 'extra key'
        },
        e : {
            'true' : ['o'],
            'false' : ['v'],
            'blah' : 'extra key'
        },
        f : {
            'true' : [],
            'false' : [],
            'blah' : 'extra key'
        },
        i : {
            'true' : [],
            'false' : ['f'],
            'blah' : 'extra key'
        },
        o : {
            'true' : [],
            'false' : [],
            'blah' : 'extra key'
        },
        u: {
            'true': [],
            'false': [],
            'blah' : 'extra key'
        },
        v: {
            'true': [],
            'false': [],
            'blah' : 'extra key'
        },
        z: {
            'true': [],
            'false': [],
            'blah' : 'extra key'
        },

    };
```

This method will return the children of a given node

```
var getChilds = function (opId) {


            var r;

            if (graphObj.hasOwnProperty(opId)) {

                var t = graphObj[opId].true.slice();
                var f = graphObj[opId].false.slice();

                r = t.concat(f);


            } else {
                console.log('No node found with the ID');
            }

            return r;

        }

        console.log(getChilds('a'));
```

> current [output] => ['e', 'i', 'u']

But I need a way to accumulate all the child nodes by recursively traversing the graph.

> required output => ['e', 'i', 'u', 'o', 'v', 'f']

Can anyone help me?

Note : This is a directed graph. No loops. Also `true` and `false` are the only keys on the node storing edge types.

Comment: Could you provide one sample function call based on the `graphObj` for the function you want? As in, define a unit test case?

Comment: Do your graphs always look like this? i.e. at the top level you have an object, at the second level several objects and at the third level arrays that contain strings?

Comment: @SpiderPig yes. It always look like that.

Comment: Is this the exact order you want? Does order matter at all? Right now, it looks like you at least want it partitioned by traversal minimum distance.

Comment: @AndrewTempleton you are correct. Order doesn't matter.

Comment: Answered with that consideration then. You should also include the `true` and `false` requirement too - as in, only traverse along those keys.

Comment: they are siblings not children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your "order does not matter" comment into consideration and also made sure to only include `['true', 'false']` as edge type keys to traverse on.

```js
var graphObj = {

        a : {
            'true' : ['e', 'i'],
            'false' : ['u']
        },
        e : {
            'true' : ['o'],
            'false' : ['v']
        },
        f : {
            'true' : [],
            'false' : []
        },
        i : {
            'true' : [],
            'false' : ['f']
        },
        o : {
            'true' : [],
            'false' : []
        },
        u: {
            'true': [],
            'false': []
        },
        v: {
            'true': [],
            'false': []
        }
    };
console.log(getChildren('a')); // [ 'e', 'o', 'v', 'i', 'f', 'u' ]


function getChildren(entry) {
    var visited = {};
    var children = {};
    traverse(entry);
    return Object.keys(children);
    function traverse (entry) {
        if (visited[entry]) {
            return;
        }
        if (!graphObj[entry]) {
            throw new Error('Node "' + entry + '" does not exist in graph!');
        }
        var edgeTypes = ['true', 'false'];
        // USE THIS LINE FOR ARBITRARY EDGE TYPES
        // var edgeTypes = Object.keys(graphObj[entry]);
        visited[entry] = true;
        edgeTypes.forEach(function(edgeType) {
            var nodeList = graphObj[entry][edgeType] || [];
            nodeList.forEach(function(nodeLetter) {
                children[nodeLetter] = true;
                traverse(nodeLetter);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution provides the exact behaviour I wanted. Kudos.

Comment: No problem :) Please update your actual question to reflect that (1) the graph is not strictly a tree and (2) `true` and `false` are the only keys on the node storing edge types, so that the question and answer make sense for future readers

Comment: Sure. I will modify it now.